# Restoring files from deleted users $Recycle.bin

Tags: windows, windows-10, data-recovery, user-profiles, recycle-bin

I'm stuck on a problem that I feel shouldn't be so hard to crack, but I can't find a good solution for it.

I was handed a user's Windows 10 VM. For some reason, the original domain user account got removed from the system a while ago and re-added and - I think for that reason - it has a different SID now.

There are still files in that old SID's $Recycle.bin and I was asked to recover all of them to their original location. Those files are all still there, I can see them with WinDirStat.

My first instinct was, restoring files that are still in the $Recycle.Bin shouldn't be too hard, right? I mean, they are all still on the drive. But damn, I'm doing research for hours now on how to do it and can't find a way. Luckily it's a VM, so the first thing I did was take a snapshot, so nothing can go wrong when I toy around with the filesystem.

Opening the folder in Explorer with my Domain-User Account of course is not helping since the files are tied to a different user. The next thing I tried was simply to rename the Recycle Bin subfolder, which includes the old SID as a folder name, to my SID. After I log into my user account then, Windows now tells me my Recycle Bin is corrupted and asks if I want to delete it. So, I reverted to my snapshot.

There are tons of tools out there that can recover deleted files from NTFS, but seemingly no tools to recover still-existing files from the recycler?

Comment: Try taking ownership of the files using the Domain Admin.    .....    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/take-ownership-of-files-or-other-objects

Answer (score 2):

I have made some tests, and it seems that deleting an account from
Computer Management does not delete the user from `C:\Users` or from
the registry.

My tests has shown that this works :

- Run `regedit` and position to the key
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`
- Inspect all the subkeys of format
  `S-1-5-21-495099530-557473056-3318008218-1001`
  until you find your profile by the value of item `ProfileImagePath`
- Once you know the SID of the deleted user account, install and run
  an alternative file-manager (not Explorer) as Administrator
  (I used [Altap Salamander](https://www.altap.cz/salamander/downloads/))
- Position to the folder `C:\$Recycle.Bin`
- Locate among the subfolders the one with the found user SID
- Inside the folder, you may right-click any file (or select any
  number of files) and select "Restore"

The files will be restored to their original folders.

You may, if this fails, just locate your files in the Recycle Bin
folder that you found above,
although with strange names such as `$RZHIN4H.txt`, without recovering
their original names. The following will help to find out the
original file-name.

When a file is deleted, two files are created in the Recycle Bin.
The first file begins with the value `$R` followed by a
random string and contains the actual contents of the
recycled file.

The second file begins with `$I` and ends in the same string
as the `$R` file and contains the metadata for that file
The `$I` file contains the original filename, path, file size,
and when the file was deleted. The Recycle Bin uses the `$I` file
when displaying its files.

Comment: First of all: Thank you for the effort of testing this on your side.

I can't tell you why, but I just tried this and after hitting "restore" in the context menu, nothing happens. No files are restored. I can only assume it is some kind of permission issue or something. I'll have to dig deeper into it to see why.

Comment: Perhaps the original folders don't exist any more. I added more information which will help you find out where a given file is supposed to go.